# JAVA nontoop/apns certificate

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

I have java application and I want to send push notification. I use nontoop/apns library. In this line of code which certificate should I use instead `cert` variable?

```
ApnsService service = APNS.newService().withCert(cert, "atajerBritecs")
                .withSandboxDestination().build();
```

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are calling  the ".withSandboxDestination()" so you will want to use the **Development Push SSL Certificate**. This can be configured in the "App Ids" section.

**Note** to configure your App in the "App Ids" section you need to be Team Agent

Comment: It should be a `*.p12` file. You can export your cert from KeyChain.

Comment: How can I use  Development Push SSL Certificate with .p12?

Comment: You would open up KeyChain find your cert right click on it select export and make sure you changed the file type to `Personal Information Exchange (.p12)`